# Horizontally align div with additional margin-left and margin-right

Tags: html, css

I would like to center a `<div />` in the `<body />` and add additional `margin-left` and `margin-right` to it.
Something like that - of course it should work :) https://jsfiddle.net/kweyn912/

Normally, I would use `margin: auto`, but in this case I want to specifically add additional `margin`, so I cannot do that.

I tried using `transform: translateX(-50%)` together with `left: 50%` and `margin-left`. That worked until I tried setting `margin-right`

*Side notes:*
I have some restrictions: I cannot use `padding` instead of `margin`. I cannot use `position: absolute` and I have to use `display: block`

Comment: Can you use `display: flex` on `body` https://jsfiddle.net/kweyn912/2/

Comment: How do you plan on centering a div with extra margin to the right or left, you know that it will not be centered anymore right?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Yes, of course. But that is the whole purpose to have an offset to the left and/or right from the center.

Comment: so what would be your desired result?

Comment: @NenadVracar Using `display: flex` is actually a good idea. I would prefer a different solution due to browser compatibility issues though

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith The desired result is to have a slightly off-centered div.

Comment: How about using `calc()` https://jsfiddle.net/kweyn912/5/

Comment: Why do you need to use `display: block`? What about `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @brouxhaha can't use `display: inline-block` because I want to add multiple block elements underneath each other

Comment: Do they all need to be centered and offset in the same way?

Comment: @NenadVracar I took a look at your solution and it works for one element. As soon as I add a second one (which should be underneath because of `display: block`) it is added as a column or if I add `flex-direction: column;` I get the same problem again: https://jsfiddle.net/kweyn912/11/

Comment: @brouxhaha No, I want to have multiple rows with different margins.

Comment: Ok. Can you edit the html?

Comment: @Horen So it should go something like this https://jsfiddle.net/kweyn912/13/. Those child divs still behave as flex items but `display: block` property affect their children not them.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your project adding

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 110px)
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  text-align: center
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kweyn912/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding to the body (or parent container) rather than the div with the div centered in the parent element. That should center the div with a gutter on the left/right.

```
div {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

body {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 20px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y16k52xt/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `margin: 0 auto` and `display: block`, you can use `display: inline-block` along with `text-align: center` on the parent element to center the divs. Then use your margin adjustments to set it off-center. Use `white-space: pre` to force each item to break to a new line.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
}

.div {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>
CENTER
</p>
  <div class="div one">
Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="div two">
  </div>
  <div class="div three">
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kweyn912/12/

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you want your element to be off center in 20px to the left (Net result of your example of margin-left: 20px and margin-right: 40px;

This is equuivalent to a transform: translateX(-20px);

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateX(calc(20px - 40px));
}
```

```html
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
```